# .NET MAUI Android how to transcode the video resolution to 720p to reduce the upload time to server

Tags: c#, android, maui, android-mediacodec, transcode

I am researching ways to reduce upload time for videos to server in .NET MAUI Android. Without transcoding the video, it takes more than 30 seconds - 1 minute to upload the video.
With IOS, I have used AVAsset and it works it's magic. However for Android, we used Xamarin.Android.MP4Transcoder in xamarin, however there are no library as such available for .NET Maui. Has anyone successfully implemented it on .NET Maui?

I have found few articles which I have tried to follow, but have not succeeded.
https://developer.android.com/media/platform/transcoding, https://ffmpeg.xabe.net/docs.html, https://bigflake.com/mediacodec/

`Any suggestion/solution is highly appreciated.`

Comment: Reminder that [asking us to recommend or find a book, tool, software library, tutorial or other off-site resource are off-topic for Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic), also you will need to [invoke platform code](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/maui/platform-integration/invoke-platform-code?view=net-maui-8.0) to access Android Java/Kotiln/C code from MAUI.

Comment: I would in place of attempts to transcode, simply set the recording mode (resolution), and thus the file will never be that large in the first place.